# Webdriverwait results in a timeout even though on debugging I found that it finds the correct element

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

This is the html:

```
<table id="dataTable">  
 <tbody>    
  <tr>  
   <tr class="alt sel">  
    <td> class="first" id="gettd"(the text that should equal suboption.text) 
    </td>
```

So this is my code:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH,"//table[@id='dataTable']//tbody//tr//td[@class='first']"),suboption.text)
```

**suboptions.text** is the expected text(the text that I need it to be)

I have debugged my application and I have found that it finds the correct element with the correct text and the only reason it fails is because the EC class is coded like " return self.text in element_text" and since both of them are strings it returns false. I don't know where I have gone wrong though.

Comment: Update the question with relevant HTML and what exactly `suboption.text` results into

Comment: I have updated my question although I didn't know how to put the HTML so I have just removed the "<>".

Comment: Please don't remove anything. Just copy the HTML and paste it within the question as it is.

Comment: @DebanjanB I actually figured that the text wasn't matching due to an extra space and being of different cases. I resolved the issue by changing the case beforehand. Thanks for your response!